# Python - speed up Pandas iteration

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

Sorry for my bad english.

This is a simplified version of my dataframe:

```
d = {'League': {5697: 'Premier League', 5695: 'Premier League', 5694: 'Premier League', 5693: 'Premier League', 5692: 'Premier League', 5691: 'Premier League', 5696: 'Premier League', 5689: 'Premier League', 5688: 'Premier League', 5690: 'Premier League', 5684: 'Premier League', 5680: 'Premier League', 5681: 'Premier League', 5682: 'Premier League', 5686: 'Premier League', 5685: 'Premier League', 5687: 'Premier League', 5683: 'Premier League', 5678: 'Premier League', 5679: 'Premier League', 5677: 'Premier League', 5674: 'Premier League', 5676: 'Premier League', 5675: 'Premier League', 5673: 'Premier League', 5670: 'Premier League', 5672: 'Premier League', 5671: 'Premier League', 5665: 'Premier League', 5667: 'Premier League', 5666: 'Premier League', 5669: 'Premier League', 5664: 'Premier League', 5663: 'Premier League', 5662: 'Premier League', 5668: 'Premier League', 5661: 'Premier League', 5660: 'Premier League', 5654: 'Premier League', 5653: 'Premier League', 5655: 'Premier League', 5656: 'Premier League', 5657: 'Premier League', 5658: 'Premier League', 5659: 'Premier League', 5652: 'Premier League', 5651: 'Premier League', 5650: 'Premier League', 5649: 'Premier League', 5642: 'Premier League'}, 'Date': {5697: '2003-08-16 13:30', 5695: '2003-08-16 16:00', 5694: '2003-08-16 16:00', 5693: '2003-08-16 16:00', 5692: '2003-08-16 16:00', 5691: '2003-08-16 16:00', 5696: '2003-08-16 16:00', 5689: '2003-08-17 15:00', 5688: '2003-08-17 15:00', 5690: '2003-08-17 17:05', 5684: '2003-08-23 13:00', 5680: '2003-08-23 16:00', 5681: '2003-08-23 16:00', 5682: '2003-08-23 16:00', 5686: '2003-08-23 16:00', 5685: '2003-08-23 16:00', 5687: '2003-08-23 16:00', 5683: '2003-08-23 16:00', 5678: '2003-08-24 15:00', 5679: '2003-08-24 17:05', 5677: '2003-08-25 21:00', 5674: '2003-08-26 20:45', 5676: '2003-08-26 20:45', 5675: '2003-08-26 20:45', 5673: '2003-08-26 21:00', 5670: '2003-08-27 20:45', 5672: '2003-08-27 21:00', 5671: '2003-08-27 21:00', 5665: '2003-08-30 13:30', 5667: '2003-08-30 16:00', 5666: '2003-08-30 16:00', 5669: '2003-08-30 16:00', 5664: '2003-08-30 16:00', 5663: '2003-08-30 16:00', 5662: '2003-08-30 16:00', 5668: '2003-08-30 16:00', 5661: '2003-08-31 15:00', 5660: '2003-08-31 17:05', 5654: '2003-09-13 16:00', 5653: '2003-09-13 16:00', 5655: '2003-09-13 16:00', 5656: '2003-09-13 16:00', 5657: '2003-09-13 16:00', 5658: '2003-09-13 16:00', 5659: '2003-09-13 16:00', 5652: '2003-09-14 15:00', 5651: '2003-09-14 17:05', 5650: '2003-09-15 21:00', 5649: '2003-09-20 13:30', 5642: '2003-09-20 16:00'}, 'HomeTeam': {5697: 'Portsmouth', 5695: 'Leicester', 5694: 'Fulham', 5693: 'Blackburn', 5692: 'Birmingham', 5691: 'Arsenal', 5696: 'Manchester United', 5689: 'Leeds', 5688: 'Charlton', 5690: 'Liverpool', 5684: 'Newcastle', 5680: 'Bolton', 5681: 'Chelsea', 5682: 'Everton', 5686: 'Tottenham', 5685: 'Southampton', 5687: 'Wolves', 5683: 'Manchester City', 5678: 'Aston Villa', 5679: 'Middlesbrough', 5677: 'Blackburn', 5674: 'Leeds', 5676: 'Portsmouth', 5675: 'Leicester', 5673: 'Charlton', 5670: 'Arsenal', 5672: 'Manchester United', 5671: 'Liverpool', 5665: 'Everton', 5667: 'Newcastle', 5666: 'Middlesbrough', 5669: 'Wolves', 5664: 'Chelsea', 5663: 'Bolton', 5662: 'Aston Villa', 5668: 'Tottenham', 5661: 'Southampton', 5660: 'Manchester City', 5654: 'Blackburn', 5653: 'Arsenal', 5655: 'Bolton', 5656: 'Charlton', 5657: 'Chelsea', 5658: 'Everton', 5659: 'Southampton', 5652: 'Manchester City', 5651: 'Birmingham', 5650: 'Leicester', 5649: 'Wolves', 5642: 'Aston Villa'}, 'AwayTeam': {5697: 'Aston Villa', 5695: 'Southampton', 5694: 'Middlesbrough', 5693: 'Wolves', 5692: 'Tottenham', 5691: 'Everton', 5696: 'Bolton', 5689: 'Newcastle', 5688: 'Manchester City', 5690: 'Chelsea', 5684: 'Manchester United', 5680: 'Blackburn', 5681: 'Leicester', 5682: 'Fulham', 5686: 'Leeds', 5685: 'Birmingham', 5687: 'Charlton', 5683: 'Portsmouth', 5678: 'Liverpool', 5679: 'Arsenal', 5677: 'Manchester City', 5674: 'Southampton', 5676: 'Bolton', 5675: 'Middlesbrough', 5673: 'Everton', 5670: 'Aston Villa', 5672: 'Wolves', 5671: 'Tottenham', 5665: 'Liverpool', 5667: 'Birmingham', 5666: 'Leeds', 5669: 'Portsmouth', 5664: 'Blackburn', 5663: 'Charlton', 5662: 'Leicester', 5668: 'Fulham', 5661: 'Manchester United', 5660: 'Arsenal', 5654: 'Liverpool', 5653: 'Portsmouth', 5655: 'Middlesbrough', 5656: 'Manchester United', 5657: 'Tottenham', 5658: 'Newcastle', 5659: 'Wolves', 5652: 'Aston Villa', 5651: 'Fulham', 5650: 'Leeds', 5649: 'Chelsea', 5642: 'Charlton'}, 'GTOT': {5697: 3, 5695: 4, 5694: 5, 5693: 6, 5692: 1, 5691: 3, 5696: 4, 5689: 4, 5688: 3, 5690: 3, 5684: 3, 5680: 4, 5681: 3, 5682: 4, 5686: 3, 5685: 0, 5687: 4, 5683: 2, 5678: 0, 5679: 4, 5677: 5, 5674: 0, 5676: 4, 5675: 0, 5673: 4, 5670: 2, 5672: 1, 5671: 0, 5665: 3, 5667: 1, 5666: 5, 5669: 0, 5664: 4, 5663: 0, 5662: 4, 5668: 3, 5661: 1, 5660: 3, 5654: 4, 5653: 2, 5655: 2, 5656: 2, 5657: 6, 5658: 4, 5659: 2, 5652: 5, 5651: 4, 5650: 4, 5649: 5, 5642: 3}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

Where GTOT is the total number of goals in the match.

For every team in the competition I want to find out the number of consecutive matches where GTOT is minor 1 and add it to a list.

I use itertuples to iterate over the dataframe, but it's very slow for a large number of matches (> 50000) and teams (> 100).
This is a semplified version of my function:

```
def calculates_overdue():
    lstTeams = [team for team in df.HomeTeam.unique()]
    lstTeams.sort()
    lstOverdue = []
    for team in lstTeams:
        overdue = 0
        mask = (df.HomeTeam == team) | (df.AwayTeam == team)
        for row in df[mask].itertuples():
            if row.GTOT < 1:
                lstOverdue.append((row.League, team, overdue, row.Date))
                overdue = 0
            else:
                overdue += 1
    return lstOverdue

print(calculates_overdue())
```

Result:

```
[('Premier League', 'Aston Villa', 4, '2003-08-24 15:00'), ('Premier League', 'Birmingham', 2, '2003-08-23 16:00'), ('Premier League', 'Bolton', 1, '2003-08-30 16:00'), ('Premier League', 'Charlton', 2, '2003-08-30 16:00'), ('Premier League', 'Leeds', 2, '2003-08-26 20:45'), ('Premier League', 'Leicester', 2, '2003-08-26 20:45'), ('Premier League', 'Liverpool', 2, '2003-08-27 21:00'), ('Premier League', 'Liverpool', 0, '2003-08-24 15:00'), ('Premier League', 'Middlesbrough', 2, '2003-08-26 20:45'), ('Premier League', 'Portsmouth', 1, '2003-08-30 16:00'), ('Premier League', 'Southampton', 2, '2003-08-26 20:45'), ('Premier League', 'Southampton', 0, '2003-08-23 16:00'), ('Premier League', 'Tottenham', 2, '2003-08-27 21:00'), ('Premier League', 'Wolves', 2, '2003-08-30 16:00')]
```

I know it's bad iterate over rows. How can I speed up these loops? Is it possible vectorize this function?

Comment: You should post on code review rather than on SO.

Comment: more importantly, you can provide some code to construct a sample dataframe, so that people can not just look the dataframe printout, but also run your code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak normally I would agree, but `pandas` has a nice builtin way to import dataframes from SO questions: `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep="\s\s+")` (I just had to adapt `sep` to not get fooled by single spaces in each cell)

Comment: @filippo: even though `pd.read_clipboard` is a nice feature, providing runnable code seems a responsiility of the OP, with a sample data included. you would still persist the dataframe in code (eg with `.to_dict()`), if you are editing/running it locally, to make the example reproducible. I would agree a printout is better than nothing, but it does not make a perfect question that is easy to deal with.

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak completely agree! it's just I've seen a lot worse (screenshots?) here than I've grown to accept somewhat parsable printouts :-)

Comment: Sorry for my bad code and thank you for your time! I added a sample of dataframe in dict form and the result.

Comment: Did you want to count the number of consecutive non-scoring matches per team, or did you want a list of non-scoring matches per team?

Comment: I want the number of consecutive non-scoring matches per team.

Answer (score 1):

Use simple python call and remove some of pandas call.

```
def testTime():
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
        #print(df)
        #print(d.keys())
        lstOverdue = []
        lstTeams = [team for team in df.HomeTeam.unique()]
        for team in lstTeams:
                mask = (df.HomeTeam == team) | (df.AwayTeam == team)
                overdue = 0
                for row in df[mask].itertuples():
                        if row.GTOT < 1:
                                lstOverdue.append((row.League, team, overdue, row.Date))
                                overdue = 0
                        else:
                                overdue += 1
def testTime2():
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
        lstOverdue = []
        for team in df.HomeTeam.unique():
                overdue = 0
                for row in df.itertuples():
                        if row.HomeTeam == team or team == row.AwayTeam:
                                if row.GTOT < 1:
                                        lstOverdue.append((row.League, team, overdue, row.Date))
                                        overdue = 0
                                else:
                                        overdue += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
        import timeit
        print(timeit.timeit("testTime2()", setup="from __main__ import testTime2", number=1000))
        print(timeit.timeit("testTime()", setup="from __main__ import testTime", number=1000))
```

see function testTime2, after running this code I observed around half of running time on my system  with the data you've provided, but it can vary on your system as well.

```
$ python3.6 test.py
21.352469262998056
39.04840800600141
$ python3.6 test.py
22.977724283999123
39.568580347000534
$ python3.6 test.py
21.838805349998438
39.85868542999742
```

This can be further reduced to number of data rows but it requires some preprocessing as follows.

1. Convert dictionary to `list` of `namedtuple`s during conversion create set of HomeTown.
2. Process the list similar to the function testTime2 process data frames.

Comment: can you please replace the image with text?

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak not sure why we have to do that, anyway changed to text.

Comment: Hmm...i try your funct, but without mask for df the execution time for DataFrame with 20000 rows increase x5.